# Reload smoke cache from file

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, path, cache

If I bake a smoke simulation, then then save-as the file as a new name, I lose the smoke cache. Is there any way to reload it?

Comment: Make sure that the name of the linked simulation (right beside the tiny physics icon) is correct. Usally this field is empty...

Comment: This could really use an answer with some screenshots, as it's not clear what "use library path" and "external" check-boxes do or how to set up a filename to store the bake in, etc.